# Angular 2 Form Getting Duplicated?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2 RC3.  I'm mostly following the documentation here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html.  When I get to "Submit the form with ngSubmit" things start to go poorly.  If I add

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
```

I get:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Reference "#heroForm" is defined several times.
```

If I remove the #heroForm attribute and add:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ...
```

Then onSubmit() gets called multiple times.  There aren't multiple entries for the form in the dom.  Why the apparent duplication, what's going on?

Here's a very simplified component that gets the "is defined several times" error:

```
import {Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: '<form #heroForm="ngForm"></form>'
})
export class Server {
}
```

This component is loaded via

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and an entry in an app.routes.ts file.  I'm using Router version 3.0.0-alpha.7.

### Solution

I was using both the old and the new forms approaches by accident. My main.ts file was doing `bootstrap(AppComponent, [provideForms()])` ... in other words I forgot to add in `disableDeprecatedForms()`. It should have been `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms() ])`

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what exactly you're doing.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Fair enough, perhaps my question should be phrased "how would one go about debugging an issue like this"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if in your form-templates you have #heroForm tag defined only once. The method onSubmit() should be defined in your component class and needs to be linked to the form in use (using ngSubmit).

If you add your components code (including the imported libs) will be easier to figure out from where you get that error.

But, I suspect you try to use the old forms mechanism. I would suggest you try to use the new approach as is quite different. Unfortunately the documentation is still work in progress and some of the examples provided are using the old approach.

In Angular2 you have 3 ways to configure forms:

1) template-driven

2) model-driven or reactive approach using low level APIs

3) model-driven but with a higher level API (FormBuilder)

Here are 2 very useful blog-posts for this:

- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/21/template-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html
- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Thank you!!  Your suspicion was correct, and those links were super helpful.  I must have been using _both_ the old and the new forms approaches by accident.  My main.ts file was doing bootstrap(AppComponent, [provideForms()]) ... in other words I forgot to add in disableDeprecatedForms().  It should have been bootstrap(AppComponent, [ disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms() ])

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but unlike the first poster I was calling `disableDeprecatedForms()`.  Since I was converting an existing old form, in my case, my component.ts file had the old

```
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
```

and...

```
directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
```

Replacing these with the `NgForm` fixed my issue.

Comment: Seems like FORMS-DIRECTIVES can be elusive.  I had some left in my code in RC4 that did not cause an issue, but do in RC5.  Perhaps because adding FormsModule at the root level exposes the issue everywhere it is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(submit)` instead of `(ngSubmit)`

Answer (score 0):

Tried everything, the only one that worked for me was change the `<button>` for a `<input type="submit">`.