# ng-submit event is called twice in the Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

The method is called twice When the ng-submit event occurring in Angular 2. How do I make a call method only once? Why does method calls twice in the angular 2?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-form-ngform',
  template: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
`
})
export class FormNgformComponent {
  onSubmit() {
    alert('test');  
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oUYE87aBwP7m52CJ6e4e?p=preview) with `2.0.0-rc.4`

Comment: its a good. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? can you please reproduce issue in plunkr?

Comment: It is only expressed thanks for your comment. Your code is no problem. and there is no particular problem in your plunkr. The only problem is specific to my project. the problem was resolved, when i set a disableDeprecatedForms () in main.ts file of my project,

Answer (score 3):

Probably another duplicate of this:

[Angular 2 Form Getting Duplicated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045944/angular-2-form-getting-duplicated)

Make sure you are bootstrapping your app like this:

```
import {disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   disableDeprecatedForms(),
   provideForms()
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the solution as `disableDepricatedForms` and `provideForms` are deprecated as per to angular version 2.0.0.rc6.

> forms: deprecated provideForms() and disableDeprecatedForms()
>   functions have been removed. Please import the FormsModule or the
>   ReactiveFormsModule from @angular/forms instead.

see: https://github.com/angular/angular/compare/2.0.0-rc.5...2.0.0-rc.6